# env->FindClass function returns null

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface, cocos2d-x

I am trying to call some functions in my java class from my cpp class. I am succesful in making these calls thrice until i call a function 4th time. I am using cocos2dx engine.

I call function in MiscManager.java from MiscManagerJni.cpp

I get the following error when i try to get classID and game crashes:

> 12-20 12:06:09.328: W/System.err(26651): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: [generic]
>   12-20 12:06:09.328: W/System.err(26651):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   12-20 08:56:35.402: D/libMiscManager(25952): Failed to find class of com/games/Game/MiscManager

I have successfully called functions 3 times in MiscManager.java class from MiscManagerJni.cpp class. But the 4th time null is returned when i call

> jclass ret = pEnv->FindClass(CLASS_NAME);

Can anyone tell me what is causing this error.

These are the functions i am using to get method id and class id

```
#define  LOG_TAG    "libMiscManager"
#define  LOGD(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG,LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)
#define  CLASS_NAME "com/games/Game/MiscManager"

typedef struct JniMethodInfo_
{
    JNIEnv *    env;
    jclass      classID;
    jmethodID   methodID;
}   JniMethodInfo;


extern "C"

{
    // get env and cache it
    static JNIEnv* getJNIEnv(void)
    {

    JavaVM* jvm = cocos2d::JniHelper::getJavaVM();
    if (NULL == jvm) {
        LOGD("Failed to get JNIEnv. JniHelper::getJavaVM() is NULL");
        return NULL;
    }

    JNIEnv *env = NULL;
    // get jni environment
    jint ret = jvm->GetEnv((void**)&env, JNI_VERSION_1_4);

    switch (ret) {
        case JNI_OK :
            // Success!

            return env;

        case JNI_EDETACHED :
            // Thread not attached
            if (jvm->AttachCurrentThread(&env, NULL) < 0)
            {
                LOGD("Failed to get the environment using AttachCurrentThread()");
                return NULL;
            } else {
                // Success : Attached and obtained JNIEnv!
                return env;
            }

        case JNI_EVERSION :

            // Cannot recover from this error
            LOGD("JNI interface version 1.4 not supported");
        default :

            LOGD("Failed to get the environment using GetEnv()");
            return NULL;
    }
}

// get class and make it a global reference, release it at endJni().
static jclass getClassID(JNIEnv *pEnv)
{
    jclass ret = pEnv->FindClass(CLASS_NAME);
    if (! ret)
    {
        LOGD("Failed to find class of %s", CLASS_NAME);
    }
    return ret;
}

static bool getStaticMethodInfo(cocos2d::JniMethodInfo &methodinfo, const char *methodName, const char *paramCode)
{
    jmethodID methodID = 0;
    JNIEnv *pEnv = 0;
    bool bRet = false;

    do 
    {
        pEnv = getJNIEnv();
        if (! pEnv)
        {
            break;
        }

        jclass classID = getClassID(pEnv);

        methodID = pEnv->GetStaticMethodID(classID, methodName, paramCode);

        if (! methodID)
        {
            LOGD("Failed to find static method id of %s", methodName);
            break;
        }
        methodinfo.classID = classID;
        methodinfo.env = pEnv;
        methodinfo.methodID = methodID;

        bRet = true;
    } while (0);
    return bRet;


   }

 void InitJni()
      {
        cocos2d::JniMethodInfo methodInfo;
        if (! getStaticMethodInfo(methodInfo, "Init", "()V"))
        {
            return ;
        }

    methodInfo.env->CallStaticVoidMethod(methodInfo.classID, methodInfo.methodID);
    methodInfo.env->DeleteLocalRef(methodInfo.classID);
}

void SaveBooleanJni(const char *key, bool value)
    {
         cocos2d::JniMethodInfo methodInfo;
        if (! getStaticMethodInfo(methodInfo, "SaveBoolean", "(Ljava/lang/String;Z)V"))
        {
        return;
    }

    jstring stringArg = methodInfo.env->NewStringUTF(key);
    methodInfo.env->CallStaticVoidMethod(methodInfo.classID, methodInfo.methodID, stringArg, value);
    methodInfo.env->DeleteLocalRef(stringArg);
    methodInfo.env->DeleteLocalRef(methodInfo.classID);
}

void SaveIntegerJni(const char *key, int value)
{
    cocos2d::JniMethodInfo methodInfo;
    if (! getStaticMethodInfo(methodInfo, "SaveInteger", "(Ljava/lang/String;I)V"))
    {
        return;
    }

    jstring stringArg = methodInfo.env->NewStringUTF(key);
    methodInfo.env->CallStaticVoidMethod(methodInfo.classID, methodInfo.methodID, stringArg, value);
    methodInfo.env->DeleteLocalRef(stringArg);
    methodInfo.env->DeleteLocalRef(methodInfo.classID);
}

void SaveLongJni(const char *key, long value)
{
    cocos2d::JniMethodInfo methodInfo;
    if (! getStaticMethodInfo(methodInfo, "SaveLong", "(Ljava/lang/String;J)V"))
    {
        return;
    }
    jstring stringArg = methodInfo.env->NewStringUTF(key);
    methodInfo.env->CallStaticVoidMethod(methodInfo.classID, methodInfo.methodID, stringArg, value);
    methodInfo.env->DeleteLocalRef(stringArg);
    methodInfo.env->DeleteLocalRef(methodInfo.classID);
}

long GetLongJni(const char *key, long defaultValue)
{
     cocos2d::JniMethodInfo methodInfo;
    long ret = 0;
    if (! getStaticMethodInfo(methodInfo, "GetInteger", "(Ljava/lang/String;J)J"))
    {
        return ret;
    }

    jstring stringArg = methodInfo.env->NewStringUTF(key);
    ret = methodInfo.env->CallStaticLongMethod(methodInfo.classID, methodInfo.methodID, stringArg, defaultValue);
    methodInfo.env->DeleteLocalRef(stringArg);
    methodInfo.env->DeleteLocalRef(methodInfo.classID);

    return (long)ret;
}

bool GetBooleanJni(const char *key, bool defaultValue)
{
     cocos2d::JniMethodInfo methodInfo;
    jboolean ret = false;
    if (! getStaticMethodInfo(methodInfo, "GetBoolean", "(Ljava/lang/String;Z)Z"))
    {
        return ret;
    }
     jstring stringArg = methodInfo.env->NewStringUTF(key);
    ret = methodInfo.env->CallStaticIntMethod(methodInfo.classID, methodInfo.methodID, stringArg, defaultValue);
    methodInfo.env->DeleteLocalRef(stringArg);
    methodInfo.env->DeleteLocalRef(methodInfo.classID);

    return ret;
}

int GetIntegerJni(const char *key, int defaultValue)
{
    cocos2d::JniMethodInfo methodInfo;
    int ret = 0;
    if (! getStaticMethodInfo(methodInfo, "GetInteger", "(Ljava/lang/String;I)I"))
    {
        return ret;
    }

    jstring stringArg = methodInfo.env->NewStringUTF(key);
    ret = methodInfo.env->CallStaticIntMethod(methodInfo.classID, methodInfo.methodID, stringArg, defaultValue);
    methodInfo.env->DeleteLocalRef(stringArg);
    methodInfo.env->DeleteLocalRef(methodInfo.classID);

    return (unsigned int)ret;
}

bool IsConnectedToNetworkJni()
{
    cocos2d::JniMethodInfo methodInfo;
    jboolean ret = false;
    if (! getStaticMethodInfo(methodInfo, "IsConnectedToNetwork", "()Z"))
    {
        return ret;
    }

    ret = methodInfo.env->CallStaticBooleanMethod(methodInfo.classID, methodInfo.methodID);
    methodInfo.env->DeleteLocalRef(methodInfo.classID);

    return ret;
}
}
```

Comment: getStaticMethodInfo(methodInfo, "SaveLong", "(Ljava/lang/String;J)V") : where is com/games/Game/MiscManager reference ? For me it seems than one argument classname is missing.

Comment: sorry i have added the rest of functions and as you can see i have defined the class name

Comment: can you show code that works for other calls ? it seems weird that it fails on class not found, while we would expect a problem on method not found or something else...

Comment: I have added all the other functions in jni class

Comment: perhaps java class is not updated in pkg or is in cache so it does not contain new SaveLong method ?

Comment: I have checked all that and it is not the case. Function not being present in class would never return class not found exception that would lead to method not being found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using JNIHelper class in cocos2dx engine.
I used getStaticMethodInfo in JNIHelper class instead of writing in my own class.